# Add inherit class on Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have generic class like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> 
    where T : class
{
    // method in here...
}
```

And I try to make this class inherit from another class, like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> 
    where T : class
    : BaseMyClass
{
    // method in here...
}
```

but It didn't work.

Is it possible generic class derived from another class? and how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyClass<T> : BaseMyClass where T : class
{
    // method in here...
}
```